# HD 3000 graphics on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, graphics, intel-graphics

I just installed 11.10 on a new Gigabyte z68ap-d3-b3, but in display settings I only had two resolution settings 800 x 600 and 1280 x 1024 (I think). My monitor supports much more. From a good bit of research, this is still unclear. Most forums say that the Intel drivers are native on 11.10.

What can I do to increase my resolution and get the proper hardware to recognize?

Thanks for any help.

Tim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out: [Ubuntu Wiki page about Resolution](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution). I hope this helps.

Comment: not really, I have two monitors in my display settings "unknown" and HSD 27". If in the display manager I click on the HSD 27", I can set the monitor to the correct resolution, but the whole OS is running on a different screen. I want to delete the "unknown" monitor and move to the HSD 27" only.